# Is it possible to achieve a transparent background with webview api?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

My chrome extension utilizes the webview api to deliver html content. My goal is to provide a transparent background for alpha webm or transparent image files that will overlay elements outside of the webview.

The style parameter works for height and width but I seem to be hitting a wall with opacity. I attempted to use the standard css method for background color. Is there another way to achieve this?

```
webview.style = 'width: 640px; height: 400px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0)';
```

Comment: Try a [frameless app window](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window).

Comment: I believe this will only work on the app itself, not the webview.